# Tags Textext Jquery plugin, a good way to save created tags with symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, jquery-textext

i work with symfony2 and now i try to save in a entity or directly in the database, the tags created in the texarea input of the [tag textext](http://textextjs.com/manual/plugins/tags.html) Jquery plug-in.
I don't know the good way to persist values (noted that in the future i want to use Filter with Suggestions functionality of the plug-in).

I think to this method:

- Take the input values in the hidden input created by the plug-in (in my case: `axxon_musicbundle_oeuvretype[tagz]`), with a jquery selector, so :

  tagz =$('input[name*="axxon_musicbundle_oeuvretype[tagz]"]').val();
  ex:=["test","test2","test3"];
- send values to the controller via AJAX, with `$('#form').submit(function()` {
- in the controller transform values (ex: `["test","test2","test3"]`) to a array.
- validate.
- send to the database.

Here a extract of my oeuvre mapping entity where i want to save the value.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="tagz",cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="oeuvre_tagz",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="oeuvre_id", referencedColumnName="id",     nullable=false)},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tagz_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)})
 **/
private $tagz;
```

In my formtype:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

switch ($options['flowStep']) {
...
case 5:
        $builder->add('tagz', 'textarea', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'required'=>false,
        ));
        break;
```

My view, i use a multistep form, craue bundle:

```
{% if flow.getCurrentStep() == 5 %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function () {
            $('#axxon_musicbundle_oeuvretype_tagz').textext({ plugins: 'tags' });
            $('#form').submit(function() {
 $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', '{{ path("axxon_music_ExtractFormTagz") }}');
                    var tagz = Array;
                        tagz =$('input[name*="axxon_musicbundle_oeuvretype[tagz]"]').val();
                            var actionController =$("#form").attr("action");
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {'tagz': tagz},
                                url: actionController,
                                success: function () {
                                    $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', '{{ path("axxon_music_add_oeuvre") }}');

               ... is this a good choice to do like that ?

                        });
                    });
    </script>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Etape {{ flow.getCurrentStep() }} / {{ flow.getMaxSteps() }}, Ajouter des mots clefs descriptifs
        </legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                {{ form_row(form.tagz) }}
            </li>

        </ul>
        {% include 'CraueFormFlowBundle:FormFlow:buttons.html.twig' %}
    </fieldset>

{% endif %}
```

My controller where i want receiving data:

```
    public function ExtractFormTagzAction(){


    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $tagz = $this->getRequest()->request->get('tagz');
    }
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong way to do it, it can be much simpler and very reusable.

In your Form, instead of

```
    $builder->add('tagz', 'textarea', array(
        'mapped' => false,
        'required'=>false,
    ));
```

you should have

```
    $builder->add('tagz', 'tag_text', .... ));
```

Then you need to build new form type, let's call it TagTextType. It's parent would be "textarea" and name "tag_text".
In form templates, you have to make

```
{% block tag_text_widget %}....{% endblock %}
```

in which you will put required javascript.

Now here comes the tricky part: in that TagTextType, you have to addTransformer that will convert existing tags into string, or explode text into array of tags. The topic is too big for me to write it here, you have really good documentation on Symfony site.

As an example for you, check my widget. I am using some other plugin, but you will get an idea:

```
{% block jquerytexttags_widget %}

    {{ form_widget(form) }} 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#{{ id }}").textntags( {
            triggers: {'@': { uniqueTags : false } } ,
            onDataRequest: function (mode, query, triggerChar, callback) {
                var data = {{ availableUsers|raw }} ;
                query = query.toLowerCase();
                var found = _.filter(data, function(item) { return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1; });
                callback.call(this, found);
            }
        } );
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

It can be tricky to start but once you build it, you will be able to use it anywhere you want. Imagine big, nested forms that will still be rendered properly with just one line

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

Cool, isn't it? :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to be clever, i will try this method tomorrow and respond you after.

Comment: It's seems to work ! i use addViewTransformer() into the buildForm function of my tagformtype. Now instead of send my resulted object by the transformer to a setter, i search to send via add (arraycollection), a idea?

Comment: You must have getTagz() and setTagz() in your entity

Comment: hello here the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532315/use-add-instead-setter-for-a-custom-field-type, i think to practice like i do with $builder->add('xxx','entity'...'multiple' => true); who haven't set but add, it's working well even if it's for a case of a single entry ; (i have already the getTagz).

Comment: It's work now, i was confused between transform and reverseTransform in the DataTransformer ! thx a lot for your support.